# Call action methods within same route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to call an "action" method within the same route.

I get an error when I'm doing something like that:

> Nothing handled the action 'refreshFoo'. If you did handle the action,
>   this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a
>   controller, causing the action to bubble.

Here is my code:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function (controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);
      this.send('refreshFoo');
   },

   actions: {
        refreshFoo: function () {
            alert('refreshed!');
        }
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rununifupono/2/edit

Any idea what is wrong? Am I using the send method properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because inside `setupController` the `IndexRoute` is not fully materialized so when you send the action it can only be handled by the `ApplicationRoute`

In order for it to work the way you would like, you need to wrap the call to send in an `Ember.run.later`

like this

```
Ember.run.later(this, function(){
  this.send('refreshFoo')
});
```

working bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rununifupono/7/edit

Answer (score 0):

define the action inside your controller. and call `controller.send('action');`

http://jsbin.com/porer/1/